# Specs for Microsoft Xinput USB devices (Xbox controllers)?

Tags: usb, specifications, hid, xbox, xinput

Has anybody found the specifications for the USB protocol used by the Xbox controllers? All I can find is the API documentation of Microsoft's implementation (Xinput). I'm trying to write a driver for OS X so Xinput controllers will appear as normal HID devices. Without the specs I'm pretty at a loss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a linux driver here https://github.com/Grumbel/xboxdrv for the XBox that should get you a long way to getting it working on Mac. I don't think the spec is available legally without signing an NDA and paying Microsoft money.